# Retrieve error from SQL Server in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm trying to show the users (in PHP) when some block of SQL actions commit failed for some reason. But it look likes PHP DBO never gets the error. This is a simplification of the actual code.

```
$conn = new PDO("dblib:host=$host; dbname=$db", $user, $pass);

$sql = "
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (1)
        INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (2)
        INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('this will throw an error')
    COMMIT
    IF @@ERROR <> 0 BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
        RAISERROR('Nops.', 16, 1)
    END";

try {
    $rs = $conn->query($sql);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'It never gets here';
}
```

How do I get that this transaction was not commited?

Comment: pdo defaults to returning false on failure, not throwing exceptions, unless you explicitly enable them. `if (!$rs) { die($conn->errorInfo()); }`

Comment: Try [`$conn = new PDO("dblib:host=$host; dbname=$db", $user, $pass, array(PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: @MarcB, I tried this, but nothing. It looks like PHP thinks that the query worked well.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, that was helpful! I could'n do like this, but I look around and this has worked:

    `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

But still, it does't solved the problem.

Comment: I think you should look into dedicate PDO functions to achieve what you want. See [`PDO::commit`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php)

Comment: Has anyone solved this??